# Error: Retrieval of mergeinfo unsupported by ‘svn://IP.Address’?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I am trying to merge a Branch to Trunk using the TSVN 'Reintegrate a branch' feature. However I get the following error.

> Error: Retrieval of mergeinfo
>   unsupported by 'svn://IP.Address'?

What is the reason for this error? Also is there some other way to merge the Branch to the Trunk.

Answer (score 1):

The reintegration feature requires the subversion server to be at least 1.5 or greater.  In addition to thise, the repository will need to be upgraded for the `mergeinfo` feature (which reintegrate relies on) to work.